# Numpy Vectorization While Indexing Two Arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, vectorization

I'm trying to vectorize the following function using numpy and am completely lost.

```
A = ndarray: Z x 3

B = ndarray: Z x 3

C = integer

D = ndarray: C x 3
```

Pseudocode:

```
entries = []
means = []
For i in range(C):
    for p in range(len(B)):
        if B[p] == D[i]:
            entries.append(A[p])
    means.append(columnwise_means(entries))
return means
```

an example would be :

```
A = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[4,5,6]]
B = [[9,8,7],[7,6,5],[1,2,3],[3,4,5]]
C = 2
D = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

Returns:

```
[average([9,8,7],[7,6,5]), average(([1,2,3],[3,4,5])] = [[8,7,6],[2,3,4]]
```

I've tried using np.where, np.argwhere, np.mean, etc but can't seem to get the desired effect. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you invert A and B ?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean.....

Comment: Could you explain how did you get to `[average([9,8,7],[7,6,5]), average(([1,2,3],[3,4,5])]`? It's not really evident from the *Pseudocode*.

Comment: Sorry. The last step is to take a columnwise average of all of the arrays in "entries", so for i=0, entries would be [9,8,7],[7,6,5] and for i = 1, entries would be [1,2,3],[3,4,5]. Then, taking the columnwise mean of these would give me [[8,7,6],[2,3,4]]

Comment: Real Python code, even if iterative, would be easier to work with.

Comment: So, shouldn't that be `if A[p] == D[i]` as @B.M. asked before?

Comment: and then append data from `B` : `entries.append(B[p])` and find its columnwise averages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by the expected output of the question, I am assuming that in the actual code, you would have :

- IF conditional statement as : `if A[p] == D[i]`, and
- Entries would be appended from B : `entries.append(B[p])`.

So, here's one vectorized approach with [`NumPy broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html) and [`dot-product`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) -

```
mask = (D[:,None,:] == A).all(-1)
out = mask.dot(B)/(mask.sum(1)[:,None])
```

If the input arrays are integer arrays, then you can save on memory and boost up performance, considering the arrays as indices of a n-dimensional array and thus create the 2D `mask` without going `3D` like so -

```
dims = np.maximum(A.max(0),D.max(0))+1
mask = np.ravel_multi_index(D.T,dims)[:,None] == np.ravel_multi_index(A.T,dims)
```

Sample run -

```
In [107]: A
Out[107]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [4, 5, 6]])

In [108]: B
Out[108]: 
array([[9, 8, 7],
       [7, 6, 5],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [3, 4, 5]])

In [109]: mask = (D[:,None,:] == A).all(-1)
     ...: out = mask.dot(B)/(mask.sum(1)[:,None])
     ...: 

In [110]: out
Out[110]: 
array([[8, 7, 6],
       [2, 3, 4]])
```

Comment: very fine ! I don't imagine a complete vectorisation in this case.

Comment: @B.M. Broadcasting always makes it possible! That dot product struck as a late thought :)

Comment: @user2069641 Could you edit the pseudocode of the question to incorporate the two changes suggested at the start of the answer? Or else the posted answers won't match up with the question.

Answer (score 1):

I see two hints :

First, comparing array by rows. A way to do that is to simplify you index system in 1D :

```
def indexer(M,base=256):
    return (M*base**arange(3)).sum(axis=1)
```

base is an integer > `A.max()` . Then the selection can be done like that :

```
indices=np.equal.outer(indexer(D),indexer(A))
```

for :

```
array([[ True,  True, False, False],
       [False, False,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

Second, each group can have different length, so vectorisation is difficult for the last step. Here a way to do achieve the job.

```
B=array(B)
means=[B[i].mean(axis=0) for  i in indices]
```

Comment: So, that `indexer` assumes inputs as integer arrays I suppose?

Comment: It seems to be the case. I don' t find vectorisable other solution for the moment.